# Writing web forms filler/submitter with QT C++

Tags: qt, automation, webkit, qtwebkit, autofill

I'm scratching my head on how to accomplish the following task: I need to write a simple web forms filler/submitter with QT C++, it does the following:

1) Loads page url
2) Fills in form fields
3) Submits the form

Sounds easy, but I'm a web developer and can't find the way how to make QT accomplish the task, I only managed to load url with QWebView object using WebKit, have no idea what to do next, how to fill in fields and submit forms. Any hints, tutorials, videos? I appreciate this.

Comment: i think when you fill up and submit the form from QWebView, it should go to the server. what are you asking then?

Comment: I don't know how to make even QWebView to fill and submit the form, I managed only to load the url. Don't know how to do "fill" and "submit" steps. For example, I load http://www.google.com and want to enter keyword "beacon" and click on "Search"...how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to automatically fill in the word "beacon" and search, or do you just want to expose this to the user?

Comment: I want the user to see the form filled in + then submit goes automatically. Looks like: form opened (url loaded), form filled, form submitted. User needs to see this to control the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QWebElement class does all the work, just reading through the class documentation gave me a full idea on how to accomplish my task. Thanks to eveyrone for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to write the logic in JavaScript that does what you want and then inject it into the page using [QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript) after it finishes loading.

There's also another way to do this; involving the document tree traversal API that's been available in QtWebKit since 4.6: [QWebElement](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwebelement.html). You'd basically process the form pretty much the same as you would do in JavaScript, except that here the API is different and more limited. It's C++ though and might be a little bit faster. I guess, this approach might be less attractive for you, given you're a web developer and probably already know JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Jakubm I was thinking about javascript, but if making it via QWebElement, how to do this?